# How do I trigger on customer delete event

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, customer, delete

I am trying to triggering my function using the event customer_delete_before.

Here is what I wrote in the config.xml:

```
<customer_delete_before>
    <observers>
        <module_customer_delete>
            <class>module/observer</class>
            <method>deleteCustomer</method>
        </module_customer_delete>
    </observers>
</customer_delete_before>
```

I've already used that xml to triggering other events but only this one does not work.

I'm using Magento 1.9.1.1.

Answer (score 2):

This looks good.

To use the module/observer syntax, you need a the xml node:

```
/config/global/models/<module>
```

If you don't have this node you should get the error:

```
Mage_Module_Model_Observer does not exist.
```

If this all is ok, make sure, that your method is called, maybe it is called but there is a buggy check in and therefore nothing happens. And make sure, the cache is cleared.